# Rpm missing folder when using "yum update"

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

So I created a new RPM for my tool.

Usually I "yum remove" the last one then "yum install" the new version.

Today I was curious and used "yum update tool"

It works and updated to the right version, BUT it is missing some folders.

So basically yum install will have a perfectly working tool
while yum update gives a tool with missing folder and scripts.

Anyone got an idea what happened?

Comment: Which folders are you missing?

Comment: Inside the RPM-plugin of the maven pom file, I mapped some folders, all the folders are missing when using yum update.

Comment: Off-topic, try http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/